# The text jumps when changing the height of a CATextLayer

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, catextlayer

When I change the height of my CATextLayer, a new text comes in from above (or below) as is depicted in the image below. How can I prevent this?

```
@IBAction func Tap(sender: UIButton) {
    counter += 1
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(8.0)
    txtLay!.frame = frameFromCounter()
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CATextLayer` draws itself via `drawInContext:` method, so any change into the rendered representation (e.g. changing `string` property) will also modify the `contents` of the layer. In your case you're resizing the layer causing the backing store resize which changes `contents` which adds an implicit animation to that property.

If you don't want the animation to happen you can use the `actions` dictionary to disable the implicit `contents` animation:

```
txtLay!.actions = ["contents" : NSNull()]
```

However, disabling `contents` animation will cause a jump in that case, so you'll probably better of not changing the bounds of the `CATextLayer` and just embed it into a superlayer to provide any additional styling/layout you want.

Comment: Ok, so it is not possible to avoid the bounce when I change the bounds. While I do not like this behaviour the answer is probably correct. I solved my problem by manipulating the affine transformation instead.